# Set navbar fixed on scroll with transition in react.js

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, navbar, react-bootstrap

I set my navbar fixed on scroll but I want it to reappear with transition instead of bumping right into the screen. I have tried many solutions but the transition effect won't kick in.

I have the following react code:

```
const [sticky, setSticky] = useState('');
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
  }, []);
 const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      windowHeight > 150 ? setSticky({ position: "fixed", top: "0"}) : setSticky({ position: "relative"});
    }
  };

return(
 <Navbar>
     <Container style={sticky} fluid className="menu">
      
    </Container>
 </Navbar>
)
```

CSS

```
.menu {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 7rem;
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 228, 228); 
   background-color:#f8f9fa;
   transition: top 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The postition property has to change in order for the effect to kick in. Therefore I added negative values for the top attribute and the same positive amount for margin. To cancel the effect for backward transition I set the css value to 0s.

```
 const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      windowHeight > 150 ? setSticky({ position: "fixed", top: "0", marginTop:"0", 
 transition: "top 1s"}) : setSticky({});
    }
  };

.menu {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 7rem;
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 228, 228); 
   background-color:#f8f9fa;
   position: relative;
   top:-30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   transition: top 0s;
   z-index: 99999;
}
```